# devise undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass, yet current_user is out of scope (i think?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to find a solution to this problem. Basically in my show page, I want users who are not signed up to be able to look at the page, while those who have signed up AND are the owner of the show page to be able to edit and delete the post.

in my Journey Controller

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
```

in my Journey Show page

```
- if user_signed_in?
        - if @journey.user_id == current_user.id
            %p= link_to "Add a Trip to this Journey", new_journey_trip_path(@journey)
            %p= link_to "Add a Travel Time to this Journey", new_journey_travel_path(@journey)
            %p= link_to "Add a Shelter to this Journey", new_journey_shelter_path(@journey)
    %p= link_to "Home", journeys_path
```

The error that I've been getting is **undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass**, and it seems to only show up when I do not log in as any user, and then proceed to visit the journeys show page.

I am assuming that it's because **current_user** is **nil** right now, and therefore no **id** is available for a **nil** class.

To counter that, I forced an if statement to see if the user is logged in or not, but that does not appear to be working.

What can I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead

```
- unless current_user.blank? 
  - if @journey.user_id == current_user.id
    %p= link_to "Add a Trip to this Journey", new_journey_trip_path(@journey)
    %p= link_to "Add a Travel Time to this Journey", new_journey_travel_path(@journey)
    %p= link_to "Add a Shelter to this Journey", new_journey_shelter_path(@journey)
  %p= link_to "Home", journeys_path
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are right, I don't know if it's a bug but I too had faced a similar problem and this workaround actually helped me!

Comment: thanks, this works! not sure why user_signed_in does not work, but this work around is perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

```
 -if current_user
     -if @journey.user_id == current_user.id
        %p= link_to "Add a Trip to this Journey", new_journey_trip_path(@journey)
        %p= link_to "Add a Travel Time to this Journey", new_journey_travel_path(@journey)
        %p= link_to "Add a Shelter to this Journey", new_journey_shelter_path(@journey)
%p= link_to "Home", journeys_path
```

Try this. This also works fine